# C++ File input not receiving

Tags: c++, random, getline

Good afternoon! I'm currently working on a program that involves taking a random line from a txt file. While working, I've come across a strange problem whereas the file is recognized, opens, and supposedly collects a string, 'message' However this variable is not changing value at all, it remains empty. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using  namespace std;

const string Fortune = "fortune.txt";;

int main()
{
   string name, junk, message;
   int month, day, year, currentDay, currentMonth, currentYear, age, randNum;
   time_t rawTime;                                              // varaible for time information
   struct tm *timePtr;                                          // structure to use to store time         information

   ifstream fin;

   timePtr = new struct tm;

   time(&rawTime);              //Gather value for time

   localtime_s(timePtr, &rawTime);

   currentDay = timePtr->tm_mday;          //Set values for day/month/year
   currentMonth = timePtr->tm_mon + 1;
   currentYear = timePtr->tm_year + 1900; 

   cout << "Enter your name: ";
   getline(cin, name);

   cout << "Enter your year of birth: ";
      cin >> year;
   cout << "Enter your month of birth: ";
      cin >> month;
   cout << "Enter your day of birth: ";
      cin >> day;

   fin.open(Fortune);        //Open file

   getline(fin, message);    //**Problem area*** Message not being received.

   srand(time(0));            //Use time to ensure true randomization

   randNum = rand() % 10 + 1;    //Pick random value between 1-10

/*   for (; randNum > 0; randNum--){          //This will help set message to the random number thus yielding a random message, though i've yet to finalize it as the message isn't working to being with
    getline(fin, junk);
   }  */


   cout << message;        //Always comes up empty

   system("pause");

   return 0;

}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: After you attempt to open a file, verify you were successful. if (!fin){ // print error message and exit }

Comment: the clue will be in the exact contents of the text file, the line-endings used and the system this has been compiled on.

Comment: I checked if the file was opened and it was not. I double checked the file, and it is named fortune.txt located within the same file as the .cpp, using VS 2013. Do I in some way need to link the cpp and .txt, or make a folder        **Edit** I wrote the txt in notepad++

Comment: @Dozar You can specify the working directory in the project properties.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear the txt file was not supposed to be in the main directory, rather, it went in the debug folder and worked fine. Thanks, and have a good one